# VSCode writing HTML in .php or .phtml files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to configure properly, or turn off all together, the autocomplete/intellisense when coding HTML in a .php or .phtml file? For example, any time I try to close any element it starts suggesting PHP things like `$_COOKIE` or constantly trying to close a not even open `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `"php.suggest.basic": false` and then install a PHP extension to provide intellisense. I recommend [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client).

<sub><sup>*Disclaimer - I'm the author</sup></sub>

Comment: I can confirm this finally solved my issue of not being able to use VSCode highlighting with HTML in PHP files.

Comment: When I write `echo '<h1>` autocompletion doesn't offer me closing `</h1>` html tag. Is this possible to have in php file?

Comment: A year later and this is still a great tool to use. Thanks!

Comment: loving that micro disclaimer haha :) intelephense is great.