# Multiple language code in the same file - Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

actually I'm working with .phtml file and it works fine for HTML part of it.

But it doesn't recognize JS inside the script: Image->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pNW9.png)

JS is total-white... how can I fix it?
OFC I need both at the same time.

Edit:
For example:

```html
<div dojoType="dijit.form.Form" id="insCliFo" jsId="insCliFo">
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onShow">
        var f1=false;
        var idWebAzienda = "";
        if('<?=$this->az?>'=="69691c7bdcc3ce6d5d8a1361f22d04ac"){
            window.progressDialog.show('Caricamento...');

            dojo.xhrPost({
                url: stdUrl("cdamodificare",'<?=$this->c?>'),
                load: function(data){
                    window.progressDialog.close();
                    data=JSON.parse(data);
                    dijit.byId('ragSoc').attr("value",data.items.RagioneSociale);
                    dijit.byId('indirizzo').attr("value",data.items.indirizzoResidenza);
                    dijit.byId('nCivico').attr("value",data.items.nCivico);
                    dijit.byId('stato').attr("value",data.items.idStato);
                    f1=data.items.idProvincia+"~"+data.items.Comune+"~"+data.items.CAP;
                    dijit.byId('cap').attr("value",data.items.CAP);
                    dijit.byId('piva').attr("value",data.items.PIVA);
                    dijit.byId('cf').attr("value",data.items.CodF);
                    if(data.items.idTipo==0)
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

the div and the script are correctly "colorized"... but the Javascript inside the script is completly "black/white"...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835993/vscode-writing-html-in-php-or-phtml-files) might be what you want.